# Solution is unbounded, optimization problem in Matlab after modification.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, matlab

[image]

[image]

The solutions seems to be unbounded even if the array A is changed to [-4 1 5; 4 1 5; 1 1 1];
Anything wrong with syntax. Could not figure out.
Any help.

Comment: It is obvious to me that the problem is unbounded. Solution: $x_1=0, x_2=-c+1, x_3=c$, where $c \geq 2$. Any $c^*$ can be increased.

Comment: Ohh I got it. Thanks @callculus.

Comment: You´re welcome.

Comment: It is $c\geq \frac12$-not $2$